# VBA How to get Multiple Selections with .Selection

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I haven't been able to find a helpful solution to this. Maybe someone on here might know the answer. My macro requires the user to have a source and destination cell. To do this the selects the source, and then hold ctrl and clicks another cell. This creates multiple selections and I can't seem to access both of them. When I use the Selection range I only have the first cell in the range. Is there another selection range, or how can I get the 2nd cell? Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Don't overtag questions, there is no VB6 question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is reference to `Areas collection of Selection`. It will go this way:

```
'for first cell:
Selection.Areas(1).Address
'for second cell:
Selection.Areas(2).Address
```

Both will return address of cells but you could change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I write a lot of code to work with the user's "unknown selection." The basic loop below is so flexible.

It could be a single cell, some cells in a row or 1 or more entire rows, some cells in a column or 1 or more entire columns, a block of cells, the ".UsedRange" or multiple combinations of a mixture of any or all of them... or of course an entire worksheet, multiple worksheets or an entire workbook

This simple example increments the contents of any and every cell in the user's selection...

```
Public Sub IncrementByOne()

     Dim ThisCell As Range _
       , ThisArea As Integer
     
     For ThisArea = 1 To Selection.Areas.Count
          For Each ThisCell In Selection.Areas(ThisArea)
               ThisCell.Value2 = ThisCell.Value2 + 1
          Next ThisCell
     Next ThisArea

End Sub
```

Ignore the fact that it is incrementing cell contents and use the method of iterating through all cells across multiple selections, unspecified at the time of coding.

Ian